# Proper Way to append to Redux State

Tags: reactjs, append, redux, state

I'm trying to append an array to a redux store.

Where I call it:

```
var hobbiesChosen = this.props.chosenHobbies;
for ( var i = 0; i < hobbiesChosen.length; i++) {
    var hobby = hobbiesChosen[i];
    this.props.fetchFilteredHobbies(hobby);
  }
```

Action creator:

```
export function fetchFilteredHobbies(hobby) {
  return function(dispatch) {
      axios.get(`${API_URL}/hobbies/?hobby=${hobby}`, {withCredentials: true})
      .then(response => {
        dispatch({
          type:FILTERED_HOBBIES,
          payload: response
        });
      })
     .catch(() => {
        console.log("Not working");
      });
    }
}
```

I have the following in my reducer:

```
  const INITIAL_STATE = { chosen:[]};

  export default function(state = INITIAL_STATE, action) {
        switch (action.type) {
          case FILTERED_HOBBIES:
            var filtered = _(action.payload.data).pluck('id').value();
            return { chosen: [...state.chosen, filtered] }
```

Filtered hobbies is run multiple times and returns a list of the id's each time.

```
[1,2]

[5]
```

Essentially, I want to append the id's of the action.payload to the chosen reducer, but I keep getting this error:

```
Warning: flattenChildren(...): Encountered two children with the same key, `undefined`. Child keys must be unique; when two children share a key, only the first child will be used.
```

Comment: Your error is coming from the place where you render these items.

Comment: If filtered is an array, don't you want `[...state.chosen, ...filtered]`?

Comment: @DavidGilbertson i tried that and got an error in my action creator

Comment: @TomFenech I added the for loop which calls the action creator. Though I think the problem is how the filtered is appended to the state

Comment: In order for us to be able to help you effectively, you need to give us a minimal example that we can use to reproduce the problem. The error you have shown from the place that you are rendering these items - presumably you're rendering an array of elements, where more than one of them has a key of `undefined`.